# EntityFramework attempting to insert null when asked to save a reference to an existing Entity in a new Entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I'm using ASP.Net MVC3, and Entity Framework 4.

Employee has an OfficeLocation, which is in another table for normalization.

I have a new Employee screen, with a drop down for Office Location:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OfficeLocation.Id, "Office Location")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.OfficeLocation.Id, new SelectList(ViewBag.OfficeLocations, "Id", "Name"))
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OfficeLocation.Id)
</div>
```

It points at the Id because I was having trouble getting the binding to work. In my controller, I load the OfficeLocation from the database, and store it back in my new Employee before saving. I've inspected the values at this point and everything is correct. I've also tried to Attach() employee.OfficeLocation, with no change. employee.OfficeLocation has no null values in it, and its state is Unchanged.

```
employee.OfficeLocation = db.OfficeLocations.Single(d => d.Id == employee.OfficeLocation.Id);
db.Employees.AddObject(employee);
db.SaveChanges();
```

And that's when I get an exception about inserting into OfficeLocations:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Name', table 'test.HR.OfficeLocations'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I've also tried the usual restarting Visual Studio, cleaning the build, et cetera.

Update: When I allowed null values, I found that it inserted a row into OfficeLocation with all null values, and then it used *the correct value* in the Employee table. What.

Comment: What happens before the three lines? Is `employee` a parameter of your action method? You say that the state is `Unchanged` but apparently EF creates an INSERT statement which is hard to understand when looking at the three lines. Can you show perhaps the full action method?

Comment: Could you please clarify this line: `employee.OfficeLocation = db.OfficeLocations.Single(d => d.Id == employee.OfficeLocation.Id);` You want to set an employee's office location to dbContext retrieved value, but to find that value, you are passing the location data you are trying to retrieve?

Comment: I've already solved it but SO won't let me answer my own question for another six hours. The problem is that in passing the selected id in the entity, MVC or EF (not sure which) is creating a blank record that it then believes it must insert when the Employee is inserted, even though it's unused. I'm working on getting IModelBinder working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of my problem was that in working around IModelBinder, I was causing something in the framework to generate new OfficeLocations that only contained an (existing) Id - which is ignored by EF when inserting, because I have it using SQL's Id generation. I worked this out by letting the columns be null and noticing that it correctly set the existing Id in the Employee table, while inserting a new, null-Named record into the other table.

So even though that new Entity was no longer referenced anywhere, the framework was trying to insert it when I saved the Employee entity that originally referenced it.

Hopefully someone else will benefit from this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an `Id` when linking these two entities together. Just introduce an `OfficeLocation`typed property in your `Employee` class, and link new office locations to your `Employee` instances whenever you create them. There is no need to have an over complexity by explicitly specifying an Id in your case.

Comment: I do have an OfficeLocation typed property in my Employee class. But I need to get the Id of that OfficeLocation somehow.

Comment: Your Office locations are created at some point, as well as employee entities are. You can mutually link them two together without the need to refer to particular Id's. Id is something that EF in this case uses internally, without you ever needing to bother about it. If you need an id, just call employee.OfficeLocation.Id. But I see that your problem that you want to get this Id for the purpose of populationg an OfficeLocation that is null. This won't work. Think about it. A non-set OfficeLocation's Id won't magically appear from somewhere. You need to explicitly set it at least once.

Comment: I'm not sure you're following me here. I am getting the id from the form data, and then using the selection on the page to load the appropriate OfficeLocation *by id*.

Comment: Ok, I now see what you mean. Right.

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens when you try to use your data model in your view.  You really should be creating custom view models that are unique to your page, with only the data required on that page.

THen, you would simply do something like this:

```
employee.OfficeLocationID = model.OfficeLocationID
```

You don't set the OfficeLocation.ID, you set the ID in the employee entity.  OfficeLocation is a navigation property that navigates to a record specified by the OfficeLocationID property of your employee.

Comment: Doesn't he set the `OfficeLocation.Id` in `DropDownListFor`? I agree that a foreign key property would make things easier but he didn't say that he has a FK property in the `Employee` class at all. I still don't see what is wrong with the code in the question.

Comment: @Slauma - He has to have a foreign key field in employee, or else the navigation property won't work.  Navigation property uses the FK property to function.  You don't set OfficeLocation.Id because that is only done when you are inserting a new record or updating the current one.  It's not used for assigning the ID.

Comment: No, both points are wrong. You can have a working navigation property without FK property and you can set the Id of course, otherwise you couldn't attach existing entities to the context.